# Swift: (Live) Streaming Audio Between Devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, streaming

Just from my own general curiosity, I was wanting to see if it was possible to stream LIVE audio between iOS devices by online using bluetooth or by "enslaving" one device over a local network—basically the same experience as a phone/Skype call. I have found tuts/information on how to stream a saved file and solutions that use a server side solution, but not exactly what I am looking for.

Anyone with solutions, information, or what not to get me started would be much appreciated.